# Dúvida - Lista dinâmica

Tags: c, lista, ponteiro, struct, lista-encadeada

Tenho a seguinte estrutura para minha lista dinâmica:

```
typedef struct DataNode

{

    int id;

} DataNode;


typedef struct Node

{

    DataNode data;
    struct Node *Next;

} Node;

typedef struct List 

{

    int size;
    Node *head;

} List;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para essa estrutura, tenho dois métodos:

Método Criar Lista:

```
List *CreateList ()

{

    List *list = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));

    list->size = 0;
    list->head = NULL;

    return list;

}
```

Na linha `list->head = NULL`, todos os elementos dentro do ponteiro  `*head` (tipo Node), receberão o valor NULL? A variável `id` e o ponteiro `*Next` receberão o valor NULL?

Método Push:

```
void Push (List *list, DataNode data01)

{


Node *node = (Node*) malloc (sizeof(Node));

node->data = data01;
node->Next = list->head;
list->head = node;
list->size++;   

}
```

Porque o ponteiro do próximo nó recebe o endereço do próprio nó ( `node->Next = list->head;` )? Na linha seguinte o nó recebe o endereço do ponteiro `*node` (tipo Node) ( `list->head = node;` ). Quando ele cria o ponteiro `*node`, ele está criando o nó na lista? E quando o ponteiro `*head` recebe o endereço do ponteiro `*node`, ele está recebendo o endereço do nó?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua função `List *CreateList ()` você aloca apenas uma estrutura `List` que contem um `int` e um ponteiro pra um `Node`, que é o seu `head`, e mais nada. E depois disso você faz o seu ponteiro apontar pra `NULL`, portanto, ali dentro não tem nenhuma estrutura que representa um `Node` de fato.

Então, quando você cria a lista, você não tem nada além de uma estrutura com um `int` e um ponteiro vazio pra um `Node`.

Ta acontecendo o seguinte:

```
List *CreateList ()

{

    List *list = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));

    list->size = 0;

    //Aqui você está fazendo a variável head da estrutura recém alocada list
    //Aponta para NULL, já que você não alocou nenhuma estrutura para ela 
    //apontar. Então, dentro do head não tem nenhuma estrutura Node de fato
    list->head = NULL;

    return list;

}
```

Na função `void Push` o novo `Node` alocado ta sendo posicionado no início da lista:

```
void Push (List *list, DataNode data01)

{

    Node *node = (Node*) malloc (sizeof(Node));

    node->data = data01;

    //Aqui você está fazendo com que o ponteiro que está definido dentro da estrutura
    //Node, aponte para um endereço de memória, que é o endereço apontado 
    //pela variável head da estrutura lista
    node->Next = list->head;

    //Aqui você está fazendo o ponteiro head da estrutura List apontar para o novo
    //Node alocado, que vai ser o novo head
    list->head = node;
    list->size++;   

}
```

Então, quando a sua lista estiver vazia e a função `Push()` for ser chamada pela primeira vez `node->Next` vai ser igual a `NULL`, já que o ponteiro `list->head` aponta pra `NULL`.

Sendo assim, pra ficar mais fácil de visualizar, você está empurrando todos os elementos da lista pra trás e colocando um novo elemento no início.

Lembrando que um ponteiro é uma variável que você declara em alguma parte do seu código que vai apontar para um endereço de memória.

Comment: Acho que consegui entender um pouco melhor. Obrigado.